# Amigos, buen día necesitando su infinito knowledge!

Tags: python

necesito desarrollar un codigo que me permita ingresar letras separadas por espacios y me devuelva cuales se repitan de forma consecutiva.
este el requerimiento
ENTRADA:
(P P P J H T T T T K K T T S S S S P O F)
SALIDA:
(P-3, J-1, H-1, T-4, K-2, T-2, S-4, P-1, O-1, F-1)
hasta el momento hice este codigo pero algo falta
"""

```
palabra = input('datos decadena: ') #Aqui input de la cadena que quieras
eliminar = "' '" #aquí señala los espacios
for i in eliminar:
  palabra = palabra.replace(i, "")#con esta funcion elimina los esacios de la cadena separada
  

letras_dic = {}  #Guarda repetición de letras
contador = 0 #Caracteres que se repiten

for letra in palabra: #Por cada letra
    if letra in letras_dic: #Si ya estaba en el dic() significa que se repite
        if letras_dic[letra] == letras_dic[letra]+1: 
            contador += 1 #Se agrega al contador
        letras_dic[letra] += 1 #Continua el conteo
    else:
        contador = 1
        letras_dic[letra] = 1 #Si la letra no esta en el diccionario, la agrega
    

print(letras_dic)
print(contador)
```

"""
OS AGRADEZCO

Comment: Parece que vino todo el curso a preguntar lo mismo, o los profesores se copian los problemas de alguna parte.

Comment: @CandidMoe parece que si.